# Jquery on event not firing for buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-delegation

I have searched for an answer for this and I understand how event delegation works but what ever I try nothing changes.
The buttons that are dynamicaly created will not trigger the on event when manually clicked however using the trigger() method works, what is wrong with my code?

```
components.forEach(function (component) {
  var id = randomId();
  var li = $.create("li").addClass("col-12");
  componentList.append(li);
  var btn = $.create("button")
    .text(component.type)
    .attr("id", id)
    .addClass("btn")
    .appendTo(li);
  componentList.on("click", "#" + id, function () {
    alert("test");
    window.circuit.push(component.create());
    circuitList.refresh();
  });
  btn.trigger("click");
});
$.create = function (arg) {
  return $(document.createElement(arg));
}
randomId = function () {
  return "id" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000) + "_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
}
```

The display is as expected, the buttons just won't fire manually.
Components is an array of objects with a type property and create method.

Comment: You should try to use `$('body').on('click', '#'+id, function() {` .

Comment: Change `componentList.on(...)` to `componentList.live(...)`

Comment: Live is deprecated, changing to body gives the same behaviour

Comment: Putting spaces between Objects and Properties is a ridiculously annoying coding practice. jQuery uses `$.each()` by the way.

Comment: Normally I have no space anywhere as I use a screenreader so it does matter for me but I've been told to use spaces more lol

Comment: Spaces* and Doesn't*

Comment: Did you create `$.create()`? I wasn't aware that was a jQuery method.

Comment: Yes, it's near the bottom of my code

Answer (score 0):

The following statement was erroneous:

```
componentList.on("click", "#" + id, function () {...
```

jQuery is smart enough to know which button was clicked just by using a class or even a tag as the second parameter.

```
$('.list').on("click", '.btn', function(e) {
```

**Details commented in Demo**

### Demo

```js
/* Had no idea what components is supposed to be */
var components = ['potentiometer', 'transistor', 'capicitor', 'transformer'];

/* On each loop $.map() will run a function */
$.map(components, function(cmp, idx) {
  var ranID = randomId();
  /* Creating nodes is easy with jQuery 
  || You can actually assign a string to a
  || jQuery object and when used with a jQuery method
  || it would be parsed into real HTML
  */
  var li = $('<li class="col-12"></li>');
  $('.list').append(li);
  /* This string is a Template Literal. a TL is a
  || string with a powerful syntax.
  */
  var btn = $(`<button id='${ranID}' class='btn' type='button'>${cmp}</button>`);
  btn.appendTo(li);
});

/* Originally the OP has a dynamically generated
|| id as the 'this', that's wrong and pointless.
|| That second parameter should be a class ex. '.btn'
*/
$('.list').on("click", '.btn', function(e) {
  var ID = $(this)[0].id;
  $(`<label for="${ID}"> ${ID}</label>`).insertAfter($(this));
  console.log(ID);
  alert(`ID:${ID} Type: ${this.textContent}`);
});


function randomId() {
  return "id" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000) + "_" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000);
}
```

```html
<ol class='list'></ol>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The id is necessary to prevent the function from being called for each component, I know that jquery can parse html however I don't like to mix it with js

Comment: @user7951676 It gets called regardless, `componentList` is a list of id's and `.btn`. If you want to avoid the insignificant increase in searching the DOM,  then use the id as the selector. Anyways, parsing HTML aside, your problem was getting the events on dynamically created elements to work. Does the `on('click'...` work?

Comment: li. on doesn't work either, without the id the handler is called for each component as the event will match each one

Comment: @user7951676 Then you don't know what event delegation is and **the event handler finds the id by using this** Further more, how can you say that it doesn't work? When you push a button...what do you see it do?

Comment: Nothing happens when I push the button, with mine or your answer

Comment: @user7951676 Here's it working: https://s31.postimg.org/8x521qm7v/2017-12-20_00-14-34.gif

Comment: @user7951676 I updated it so the result is returned on an alert()